# Proguard android library referencing pure java modules

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-proguard

To simplify, my setup has android library (defined in gradle as `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`) with pure java module dependency (defined in gradle as `apply plugin: 'java'`). I can easily proguard android library itself but how to proguard both android library and its mentioned dependence?